# Python Application in right click menu of OS X

Tags: python, objective-c, macos

I know that there is the PyObjC bridge is OSX and what I want to do is to put a python application/script in the rightclick context menu of OS X. there is the [OnMyCommand](http://free.abracode.com/cmworkshop/on_my_command.html) plugin but I dont think that supports python. I've had a look at how to do it in Carbon/ Objective-C and i'll admit it im a wuss and am just not smart enough yet to grok how to do it (I aint even close to groking it actually.)

Anybody got any idea's on how I might go about this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the [documentation](http://free.abracode.com/cmworkshop/new_empty_file_tutorial.html) for OnMyCommand (neat find by the way) I would say you shouldn't have any problem using a Python script. Just make sure the Python script is executable and in your PATH.

Going along with the example in [1](http://free.abracode.com/cmworkshop/new_empty_file_tutorial.html), instead of executing `touch` you would simply execute your Python script.

Comment: seems like youre right. Given you the answer as yours was the best one. Chalk it up to "actually read the manual"